# Good Options for Java Developer who needs Inexpensive Web Hosting

Tags: java, hosting, web-hosting

As a programmer with limited experience, and interest, in server management, what are some good options for having space available online that makes getting to the actual development and deployment of Java web applications simple?

Needs:
- ability to create, or at least manage a database through non-command line interface, even if it just requires using a remote connection to the database manager
- deployments can be done from remote server
- hooking up a domain to a Java server context needs to be easily done (I don't want to manage something like mod_jk with Apache manually)

Comment: @BalusC May I know which hosting platform you actually ended up utilizing and what your experience was like? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another cheap option in addition to others already listed:

http://vpsland.com/windowsplans.html

http://vpsland.com/linux_vps_plans.php

Answer (score 10):

It all depends on how cheap you want to go.  Google App Engine is the cheapest (free) for small sites, but if your site gets very little traffic you have to wait for the JVM to start up.

Here are some links to check out:

Inexpensive VPS/Cloud:

http://www.joyent.com/services/cloudhosting/

http://performancehosting.net/hosting.php

http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/virtual-dedicated-servers.aspx

A little less expensive, but very popular:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

If you are a Java dev and are interested in a very fun, simple Java-based web framework and hosting package:

http://www.playframework.org/

http://www.playapps.net/

More reading:
http://mediatemple.net/

http://www.rackspacecloud.com/

http://mor.ph/products

http://www.rightscale.com/

http://www.cloudfoundry.com/

Comment: 2017 Update: AWS, Google Cloud, and Heroku are all good options that I've used.  Heroku especially is easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

- Virtual Private Server (VPS) - rather cheap, prices start at around 13 dollars / month
- [Google App Engine](https://code.google.com/appengine/) (but it imposes some limitations)

Answer (score 5):

[Jelastic](https://jelastic.com) (Java Elastic) provides an advanced cloud hosting platform for Java developers. It simplifies provisioning of dev, test and production environments for simple and complex Java projects, automates horizontal scaling, load balancing and clustering. It also provides a unique vertical scaling which actually saves a lot of money and enables scalability for legacy applications that were not designed as microservices.

[image: Java Elastic Cloud Hosting]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something cheap and at the same time you would like to deploy in a simple way, you should take a look at some PaaS providers as they usually offer a free tier and they also permit you to deploy without installing or configuring any software in the user end. You just need to have your .war file and to deploy it.

Not all the PaaS support the same stacks. If you are only interested in a specialized java a PaaS a simple search with the key words "java platform as a service" will give interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IBM [Bluemix](https://ace.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dW%20CloudOE%20content-_-j-hangman-app-_-article) It has a 30 day free trial and after that you are charged for the time that your apps run and the memory that is used, calculated as GB-hours, so you only pay for what you use. Also there are a lot of tutorial about how to use Bluemix, here you can find a Java,Ajax and Cloudant (database) example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Also [check out Oxxus.net java hosting offers](http://www.oxxus.net). They have java-ready VPS servers that come loaded with whatever JVM you want and also clustered solutions for scalability. They've been hosting java since 2003 and have no negative reviews online so it's worth checking out.